# What is wrong with my proxy, it does not work?

Tags: node.js, git, npm, server

I don’t know what happened, since the Internet works for me. But I don’t copy git repositories and do not go to github
**git bash**

```
Rahat@Rahat-PC MINGW32 /c/users/rahat/downloads
$ git clone https://github.com/RahatMelsov/django-blog-app.git
Cloning into 'django-blog-app'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/RahatMelsov/django-blog-app.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com

Rahat@Rahat-PC MINGW32 /c/users/rahat/downloads
```

---

And when I want to install some kind of module from the NPM using the node.js, it produces such an error:
**cmd**

```
C:\Users\Rahat>npm install --save react react-dom
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/react failed, reason: get
addrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Rahat\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-27T20_29_06_
174Z-debug.log
```

I think this is because of my proxy, as everywhere this "word" appears. Maybe something wrong with wi-fi?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJYQQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

> since the Internet works for me

No it doesn't

> But I don’t copy git repositories

As the error message from git explains the problem is not with git but your internet connectivity from your MING subsystem.

If you didn't understand what git was telling you, npm tells you the same thing in different words.

If npm is running natively in MS-Windows rather than under MING, then nothing on the machine can to talk to the internet.

> Maybe something wrong with wi-fi?

I thought you said the internet was working for you?

Answer (score 0):

create a **.npmrc** file if not available and do the proxy setting .

case 1 : your personal or office system where proxy not required.

```
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

case 2 : Office system and proxy required.

```
registry=link from whihc node packages can be downloaded , say Artifactory.

https_proxy=http://userId:password@proxyIP:Port
https_proxy=http://userId:password@proxyIP:Port
```